# Spring batch chunk size

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new in spring batch and I am stuck in something basic I think.

I create a Job configuration like this:

```
//reader
@Bean
public ItemReader<UnprocessedTrek> atReader() {

    //AnalyzeTrekItemReader reader = new AnalyzeTrekItemReader();
    JdbcCursorItemReader<UnprocessedTrek> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<UnprocessedTrek>();
    reader.setSql("SELECT * FROM " + UnprocessedTrek.TBL_NAME);
    reader.setRowMapper(new UnprocessedTrekRowMapper());
    reader.setDataSource(rntDataSource);
    reader.setFetchSize(0);
    return reader;
}

//processor
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<UnprocessedTrek, Document> atProcessor()
{
    AnalyzeTrekItemProcessor processor = new AnalyzeTrekItemProcessor();
    return processor;
}

//writer
@Bean
public ItemWriter<Document> atWriter()
{
    AnalyzeTrekItemWriter writer = new AnalyzeTrekItemWriter();
    return writer;

}

@Bean
public Step analyzeTrek()
{
    return steps.get("analyzeTrek")
            .<UnprocessedTrek, Document> chunk(50)
            .reader(atReader())
            .processor(atProcessor())
            .writer(atWriter())
            .build();
}
```

My problem is that when the size of items processed is inferior as 50 the writer is not called. What I am missing in my configuration ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you share the reader, processor and writer config as well?

Comment: @MichaelPralow added.

Comment: AnalyzeTrekItemWriter what is this class doing ?

Comment: @NinadIngole : this class write items in MongoDB server

Comment: "the writer is not called"...what happens?

Comment: @MichaelMinella as I said when the number of items is not raised (50 in this example) the writer is not called. If I have 60 items, for ex., so the writer will be called once ( first 50 items ) and the extra 10 items will not be send to the writer. It seems to work like a modulo.

Comment: But what happens?  Does the job end?  Does it hang?  Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: @MichaelMinella No the job didn't end. From my example in last comment the processor is called for the last 10 items but the writer is not called.